# Android drag and drop image crash on ICS (4.0.3)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, crash, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

What my app does is quite simple:

It displays the thumbnail images of all images on the sdcard on a GridView
and an icon on the corner of these thumbnails so the user can touch it to start
dragging a shadow of the image.

This shadow can be dropped on views that have been set a drag listener. When that
occurs, a new intent will be called with the image filepath Uri as extra for the 
new intent. So far, so good.

The problem happens when i start dropping the shadow on views that doesn`t have any
drag listener, eventually freezing the screen and crashing the mobile device!

All i get in the stack trace is this:

```
03-29 14:24:14.803: I/ViewRootImpl(2496): Reporting drop result: false
03-29 14:24:14.803: W/WindowManager(274): Drag is in progress but there is no drag window handle.
03-29 14:24:15.062: I/ViewRootImpl(2496): Reporting drop result: false
03-29 14:24:15.062: W/WindowManager(274): Drag is in progress but there is no drag window handle.
03-29 14:24:15.294: I/ViewRootImpl(2496): Reporting drop result: false
03-29 14:25:06.972: I/Process(274): Sending signal. PID: 274 SIG: 3
03-29 14:25:06.972: I/dalvikvm(274): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-29 14:25:07.092: I/dalvikvm(274): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-29 14:25:10.012: W/ActivityManager(274): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2c09ce28 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2bf0c4e8, started 10009ms ago
03-29 14:25:10.012: W/ActivityManager(274): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bf0cd08 ReceiverList{2bf0c660 274 system/1000 local:2bf0c4e8}}
03-29 14:25:20.022: W/ActivityManager(274): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2c09ce28 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2bef04e8, started 10008ms ago
03-29 14:25:20.022: W/ActivityManager(274): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bef0760 ReceiverList{2bef06e8 274 system/1000 local:2bef04e8}}
03-29 14:25:37.092: W/Watchdog(274): WATCHDOG PROBLEM IN SYSTEM SERVER: com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService
03-29 14:25:37.102: I/Process(274): Sending signal. PID: 274 SIG: 3
03-29 14:25:37.102: I/dalvikvm(274): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-29 14:25:37.182: I/dalvikvm(274): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-29 14:25:37.192: I/Process(274): Sending signal. PID: 475 SIG: 3
03-29 14:25:37.192: I/dalvikvm(475): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-29 14:25:37.202: I/dalvikvm(475): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-29 14:25:39.204: I/Watchdog_N(274): dumpKernelStacks
03-29 14:25:39.492: I/CrashMonitor(1186): CrashMonitorService: invokeService: android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED
03-29 14:25:39.492: W/Watchdog(274): *** WATCHDOG KILLING THE SYSTEM: com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService
```

My adapter class (where i execute view.startDrag() method):

```
public class ImageCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final static int mImageColumnID = 0;
    private Options mOptions = new Options();;
    private Cursor mCursor;

    public ImageCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        mCursor = cursor;
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        ImageThumbnailLoader imageLoader = new ImageThumbnailLoader(
            holder.thumbImg, cursor.getLong(mImageColumnID),
            context.getContentResolver(), false);
        imageLoader.execute();
//      holder.thumbImg.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
//                  context.getContentResolver(), cursor.getLong(mColumnID),
//                  MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, mOptions));
        holder.dragImg.setTag(holder.thumbImg);
        holder.dragImg.setId(cursor.getPosition());
        holder.dragImg.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    mCursor.moveToPosition(v.getId());
                    int dataColumn = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                    ClipData dragData = ClipData.newPlainText("filename",
                        mCursor.getString(dataColumn));
                    DragShadowBuilder shadow = new DragShadowBuilder((View) v.getTag());
                    return v.startDrag(dragData, shadow, null, 0);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        Log.i("Prototype", "bindView : " + cursor.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("Prototype", "newView : " + cursor.getPosition());
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
        return view;
    }


    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumbImg, dragImg;

        ViewHolder(View base) {
            thumbImg = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            dragImg = (ImageView) base.findViewById(R.id.dragImage);
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas/clues on what`s going on here? I would really appreciate a hand on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a switch case statement in your 'onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)' Method, then you should add there the case 'DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION'. There you can define, what should happen if your icon/image is placed on a NON-Drag Field.

Here is an example:

```
public class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

  @Override
  public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch ( action ) {
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        owner.removeView(view);
        RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) v;
        container.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    break;
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I have implemented this on my class and the freezes still occur.
Its not always that happens, only when i try to drag an icon repeatedly...

Comment: @DJayC No, i did not. Ended up implementing my own drag and drop framework.

Comment: @ImNotAnUser Yeah, I ended up doing the same thing.  What device were you on?  I notice I didn't see the crash on Jelly Bean, and I was able to find a commit to the JB source that fixed some issues with Drag and Drop and input channels.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue in that I did not want a layout to accept the drop action.

Attach a drag listener to your view via the setOnDragListener.

view.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

Check whether the target view in the onDrag event is your required view. If the condition is false, put your desired code there.

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

  switch (event.getAction()) {
  case case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
         //check whether it has not been dropped onto your view
          if(v!=view)
              //your code here
}
```